# mongoDB - find first x documents, where rolling sum of their fields exceeds certain value

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB collection of documents like this:

```
{
"_id": 1,
"size": 10,
"name": "ABCD"
}
```

I would like to:

- Sort them by "name" in ascending order
- Return **however many first** documents from the result, where **their cumulative "size"** will be greater or equal to 100

I have briefly looked into $redact stage of aggregation framework, but I can't figure out whether I can store the cumulative sum outside the document. What would be the best approach to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

An example collection:

```
{ "name": "AAAA", "size": 2}
{ "name": "BBBB", "size": 4}
{ "name": "CCCC", "size": 3}
```

So the query would be designed to return the first X documents, in order of their appearance, when their cumulative size reaches 6.

So output will be (because 2+4 is 6):

```
{ "name": "AAAA", "size": 2}
{ "name": "BBBB", "size": 4}
```

The only thing I can think of is to use the Cursor on the application level, and keep adding documents to result set, incrementing the "size" counter by value in the document. But is there a way to do that using Aggregation framework, for example?

**EDIT2:**

I also came across the 'rolling sum' terminology and using map-reduce. Sadly, in my case I would want the map-reduce operation to terminate when a global scope variable gets to or over a certain value, and I don't think it's possible (mapReduce will go over all documents fed to it at the outset).

Comment: sort by name and get documents whose size value >=100. What else do you want to do (regarding whose sum are you talking about).

Comment: `db.collection.find({ "size": { "$gte": 100 }}).sort({ name: 1 })`

Comment: @Helpinghand it's the cumulative size of documents that I'm talking about. Let me clarify the question

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet sorry, I want' very clear. let me re-phrase the question

Comment: what do you mean by "however many first"

Comment: @Helpinghand added an example, thank you

Comment: @tony have you got the solution?

Comment: @Helpinghand not within the database, no